# Changing of app icon layout in iOS

Tags: ios, layout, icons

I want to change the app icon's layout to circle in iOS. Can you please help me with a solution to this.By default, it is a square with rounded corners. I want to make it in a custom format. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: no it is not possible. you have to use app icon as per [Guideline of apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/)

Answer (score 0):

All about App Icons can be found [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html)

From this guidelines:

> Note: All icon images must be in PNG format. Icon images may include an alpha channel but should not include any transparent regions.

So it is not possible to make circular app icons on iOS.